# AppInventor - Why does ".initialize" not work?

Tags: app-inventor

In my application I want to run some code when opening a screen. AppInventor has a function ".initialize" for this, but it does not seem to work.

When I open the screen the code does not run, while the code is fine because it does work when I trigger it with something else than the ".initialize" function.

I have these code blocks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba3LI.jpg as you can see the code inside is exactly the same but it doesn't run when the screen initializes while it does work when I check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to get tiny DB values when the screen initializes. Perhaps try adding another component like a clock with a timer and then using the same blocks you have on .initialize after a certain time interval of some 500 milliseconds. Since as you say it doesnt work on the .initialize block but does work when the checkbox is changed.

Answer (score 0):

What's the code?
You have to give us an idea of what it is your working with for us to be able to try and help you. Trust me man the chances of your question getting answered here are slim even if you pit it perfectly. 
This is way too vague for somebody to even attempt to answer.
Next time make sure you ask with specifics.

Comment: I have these code blocks: https://imgur.com/a/y0ZMqa3 as you can see the code inside is exactly the same but it doesn't run when the screen initializes while it does work when I check the checkbox.